# Combine two images with a mask in python/cv2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have three images:

warp.png

[image]

weft.png

[image]

pattern.png

[image]

I would like to combine them so that

- the colors in `warp.png` show where `pattern.png` is black
- and the colors in `weft.png` show where `pattern.png` is white

So far iǘe tried

```
weave = warp * pattern + weft * np.logical_not(pattern)
```

which results in a botched picture:

[image]

What should I do instead? Obviously, I could go over the picture pixel by pixel, but I guess there is a better method...

Comment: [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is one option, but I see no problem with your way. Except where you put `np.logical_not` in the wrong place because white is True and black is False.

Answer (score 3):

Just expanding on the comment by @ken suggesting using `np.where()`. Basically, `np.where(condition, image1, image2)`  selects the pixel from the first image where a condition is true and from the second image where it is not true, which makes the code trivial:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read warp and weft as kindly supplied by Rotem
warp = cv2.imread('warp.png')
weft = cv2.imread('weft.png')
# Read the mask as greyscale
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Choose "warp" where mask is true and choose "weft" elsewhere
weave = np.where(mask[...,np.newaxis], warp, weft)
```

The only tricky part is adding a new axis to the mask so that its shape changes from (256,256) to (256,256,1) so that it broadcasts to match the (256,256,3) of the colour images.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `pattern` dtype is `np.uint8` with values `0` and `255` (not `0` and `1.0`), we may use bitwise operations instead of scaling:

```
weave = (warp & np.bitwise_not(pattern)) | (weft & pattern)
```

---

- `np.bitwise_not(pattern)` - invert `255` and `0` values.
- `&` applies "bitwise and" - `weft & pattern` equals `weft` where pattern=255, and 0 where pattern=0.
- `|` applies "bitwise or"

As commented by Ken, the `bitwise_not(pattern)` should apply the "`warp` part".

---

For demonstrating the solution, we my create modified versions of `warp` and `weft`.
We may create stripes with 8 different colors, and make the colors of `warp` and `weft` to be different.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

warp = cv2.imread('warp.png')
weft = cv2.imread('weft.png')
pattern = cv2.imread('pattern.png')

# "Fixing" the input images, for getting a nice result (not part of the original question) - used for demonstration.
################################################################################
rows, cols, ch = pattern.shape
warp2 = warp.copy()
for i in range(0, 8, 2):
    warp2[:, i*cols//8:(i+1)*cols//8, :] = warp[:, (i+1)*cols//8:(i+2)*cols//8:, :]//2

weft2 = weft.copy()
for i in range(0, 8, 2):
    weft2[i*rows//8:(i+1)*rows//8, :, :] = weft[(i+1)*rows//8:(i+2)*rows//8:, :, :]//2
weft2 = weft2[:, :, ::-1]  # Revere the RGB order for getting different colors
################################################################################

# Use bitwise operations
weave = (warp2 & np.bitwise_not(pattern)) | (weft2 & pattern)

# Write the output for testing:
cv2.imwrite('warp2.png', warp2)
cv2.imwrite('weft2.png', weft2)
cv2.imwrite('weave.png', weave)
```

---

`warp2.png`:
[image]

`weft2.png`:
[image]

`weave.png`:
[image]